# Why map() method is not listed on w3schools.com

Tags: javascript, web-standards

I'm new to JavaScript. And I'm now using [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) as my major resource of references of the language (including HTML and CSS).

What I just found is that the map() method of Array object is not listed on the site, [check the reference page here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) . After some research, I found that this method is defined in ECMAScript 5 and it's already [widely supported on the modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/).

But why it's not listed on w3schools.com. Is there a good reason not using that? Or it just shows the incompleteness of w3schools.com and I should not using that for study?

Comment: Just use it as one of your references. They all have there flaws

Comment: Why is this a question on Stack overflow? Ask W3School about their site instead.

Comment: @ztripez I suppose I'm asking a question about something related to "learning JavaScript". Is it still off topic?

Comment: @Reinhard your question isnt about javascript, but W3Schools - and I think many here would agree that MDN is your best resource, not the outdated W3Schools. They have an article on map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `whys` you need are listed on http://www.w3fools.com

Full list used to be listed on w3fools when it first started - refer to webarchive
https://web.archive.org/web/20110117085131/http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want on this!